# MemoryStream.Position or MemoryStream.Seek does not work (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, memorystream

I have a memorystream in a silverlight app. I have to copy this memorystream to a filestream object. If I call:

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
memoryStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

It does not work, I debug the application, check the properties of the memorystream, and the position still points to the end of the file. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that another of your properties is being triggered in the debugger, and reading through the stream?

Rather than using the debugger, what happens if you log (or show on a message box):

```
Log("Position = " + stream.Position);
stream.Position = 0;
Log("Position = " + stream.Position);
```

Does that show the same non-zero number twice? I find it hard to believe that `MemoryStream` is that broken.

Btw, a simpler way of using `MemoryStream` for copying than *manually* copying everything is to call [`WriteTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.writeto.aspx) with the `FileStream` as an argument.

Comment: Even without the debugger, It does not work, because I try to iterate through the bytes of the memory stream, and the for loop does not work, as the pointer is at the end of the file

Comment: @VolkanUzun: Have you tried the logging I've shown? Does it even show a non-zero position beforehand? Could you show a short but complete example demonstrating the problem, e.g. one to just write out a few random bytes?